# Validation Box, a bit hard

Tags: javascript, jquery

User must click a service from a column. Code in function is too big and propietary, cant modify, code is working fine, this is the important part.

```
    this.addDeliveredServicePressed = function() {        
        //big code ...............................
        //Important bit ORIGINAL

        var rowCallback = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
          /* Set onclick action */
          nRow.onclick = deliveredServiceClicked;
          return nRow;
          //Follow up code...
        }
    };
```

When clicking on a row, it calls a function deliveredServiceClicked, which does something, then returns it and the follow up code, builds the table.

I used a Jquery function in the rowCallback function with a Jquery Plugin, the problem is boss want the "box" to "EXACTLY" match the css style of the other boxes on the webpage. So what i did was create some kind of "bridge" on nRow.onclick, to call an HTML DIV with the YES/NO option (i did this to use the CSS classes already created), the No option is a close function, the YES function, should run a function that changes a global variable so it validates and run the nRow.onclick=deliveredServiceClicked;

This is the Primary Function after i changed it.

```
   this.addDeliveredServicePressed = function() { 
      var rowCallback = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
         /* Set onclick action */
         if (confirmedglobal==1){
            alert("serviceclicked");
            nRow.onclick = deliveredServiceClicked;
            confirmedglobal=0;
           //This confirmedglobal=0, puts the global back to 0 so after the first YES it resets it back to 0, so it keeps asking.
            return nRow;
         }else if (confirmedglobal==0){
            //This is the redirect to the HTML dialogue, using some util
            nRow.onclick = ConfirmService;
         }
      };
```

This is my function for the YES onclick

```
   this.Confirmed = function (){
      confirmedglobal = 1;
      addDeliveredServicePressed();
       //diag box close util to be added, not now
   }
```

So to resume this function, in my plan, should put the global on 1, and then execute function addDeliveredServicePressed, which is the main function, from the start so it updates the marks that i want. What it is doing right now is setting the global to 1, but its NOT going to addDeliver.... so it changes the global, but nothing happens, when i close and open again it no longers ask for YES NO, but it adds and builds the table perfectly fine.

So my question is this, why is addDeliveredServicePressed(); on my Confirmed function not being executed, what other approach for this would you use??, ive think about a lot of options and i came with global variable and the if as the better solution even tho global variables are not the best option.

In any case im a noob in js. so its not like im probably not missing anything

FOLLOW UP TO QUESTION

on the same js there is only this more

```
   deliveredServicesTable = $('#deliveredServices').dataTable( {
        "bDestroy": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": translate.msg("info.no.delivered.services"),
            "sInfo": "",
            "sInfoEmpty": "",
            "sZeroRecords": ""
        },
        "bFilter": false,
        "fnRowCallback": rowCallback,
        "fnHeaderCallback": headerCallback,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aoColumns": columns,
        "sScrollX": "95%",
        "sScrollY": "158px",
        "aaData": (sessvars.state.visit != null &&
            sessvars.state.visit.currentVisitService != null &&
            sessvars.state.visit.currentVisitService.visitDeliveredServices !== null ?
            sessvars.state.visit.currentVisitService.visitDeliveredServices : null)
    });
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        deliveredServicesTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    } );
}
```

and on a file called "jquery.datatables.js" there is like a jquery plugin for some use on functions but i think i dont need anything from there, and its like a 35k lines code, and there are multiple functions

```
/**
 * This function allows you to 'post process' each row after it have been
 * generated for each table draw, but before it is rendered on screen. This
 * function might be used for setting the row class name etc.
 *  @type function
 *  @param {node} nRow "TR" element for the current row
 *  @param {array} aData Raw data array for this row
 *  @param {int} iDisplayIndex The display index for the current table draw
 *  @param {int} iDisplayIndexFull The index of the data in the full list of
 *    rows (after filtering)
 *  @dtopt Callbacks
 *
 *  @example
 *    $(document).ready(function() {
 *      $('#example').dataTable( {
 *        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
 *          // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
 *          if ( aData[4] == "A" )
 *          {
 *            $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' );
 *          }
 *        }
 *      } );
 *    } );
 */
"fnRowCallback": null,
```

Comment: You might be missing the relevant part from the samples.  In what you've shown, the `addDeliveredServicePressed` defines a callback function, but does nothing with it (doesn't return it, call it, or assign it), so calling the function as you have shown here *shouldn't* do anything besides set `confirmedglobal`.

Comment: the follow up code does this                 selectDeliveredServiceTable = util.buildTableJson({"tableId": "selectDeliveredServiceTable", "url": url,
                    "rowCallback": rowCallback, "columns":columns, "filter": true, "headerCallback": headerCallback,
                    "scrollYHeight": "300px", "emptyTableLabel": "info.no.delivered.services.defined"});
            }

Comment: That's not what I mean.  The function where you're executing the follow up code is defined in the code in question, but never executed.  We're missing the part where something is actually done with `rowCallback`, as in the code above it's just defined and left for garbage collection.

Comment: added a few more lines of code in main